# phpmyadmin - category as dbname?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I don't know how to specify the title for the question, and that's why i cannot find the answer by my own.

I'll try to explain what I mean.

We have a database. Then, on the list of the databases there's something like category? it's unclickable and it's bold. It contains three databases preceded by underscore and each of this databases contains tables.

It looks something like:

**Category**

```
> _something1
        table1, table2, table3...
> _something2
        table1, table2, table3...
> _something3
        table1, table2, table3...
```

How it's called and how can I reach the effect above?

Comment: I'm pretty lost on what you are asking.  Can you point out what you mean on the phpmyadmin demo (http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/)?

And you want to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, "Category" is a prefix for database names. So your databases names are

category_something1
category_something2
category_something3

They are displayed in a collapsible/expandable tree.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from the question, You want to write a program that will show 6 rows like this:

> **Category:**
>   -Something 1
>      table1,table2,table3
>   -Something 2
>       table1,table2,table3
>   -Something 3
>       table1,table2,table3

First of all you would need to form the rows in ASC order.

Change some thing like this :

```
    Array(Category,
     Category_something1,
     Category_something2_table1,
     Category_something2_table2,
     Category_something2_table3,
     Category_something2,
     Category_something3_table1,
     Category_something3_table2,
     Category_something3_table3,
     Category_something3,
     Category_something1_table1,
     Category_something1_table2,
     Category_something1_table3,)
```

into :

```
 Array(Category,
     Category_something1,
     Category_something1_table1,
     Category_something1_table2,
     Category_something1_table3,
     Category_something2,
     Category_something2_table1,
     Category_something2_table2,
     Category_something2_table3,
     Category_something3,
     Category_something3_table1,
     Category_something3_table2,
     Category_something3_table3,)
```

Then Run a loop that splits each string into 3. if second value/third is not present print as heading/category else print as item/something.

```
While(ArrayKey is not equal to count(Array))
{
    SplitString(ArrayCurValue,"_",$VarValue1,$VarValue2,$VarValue3); //split current string into 3 vars where _ is present
    if($VarValue2 == "")
    {
        Print "<b>",$VarValue1,"</b>";
    }else{
        if($VarValue3 == "")
            {
                Print " -",$VarValue2;
            }else{
                Print "    -",$VarValue3;
            }  
    }
}
```